# Слайдер как на амазоне

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем добрый день!

Вообщем хочется сделать слайдер, как на амазоне, даже не сам слайдер, а возможность увеличить фото и когда водишь мышкой по картинке она двигается (чтобы можно было рассмотреть детали)

Моя попытка провалилась, вот код HTML:

```
<div class="main">
<div id="carousel" class="slider">
  <div data-thumb="https://allstringsnylon.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/c/o/cordoba-15cm-concert-uke-top_lrg_1.png"><img src="https://allstringsnylon.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/c/o/cordoba-15cm-concert-uke-top_lrg_1.png" alt=""></div>
  <div data-thumb="http://rolandblog.ca/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/13082_MATON-UKULELE-CEDAR-TOP__98800_zoom.jpg"><img src="http://rolandblog.ca/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/13082_MATON-UKULELE-CEDAR-TOP__98800_zoom.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div data-thumb="http://www.lunaguitars.com/productimages/uketribal6/uketribal6.jpg"><img src="http://www.lunaguitars.com/productimages/uketribal6/uketribal6.jpg" alt=""></div>
</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
$(".slider").slick({
    autoplay: true,
    dots: true,
    customPaging : function(slider, i) {
        var thumb = $(slider.$slides[i]).data('thumb');
        return '<a><img src="'+thumb+'"></a>';
    },
});
  var trueHeight,
      trueWidth,
      img;
  $('.slick-slider div img').hover(function(e){

    img = $(this);
    trueHeight = $(this).height();
    trueWidth = $(this).width();
    $(this).css('position', 'absolute');
    var imgHeight = $(this).prop('naturalHeight');
    var imgWidth = $(this).prop('naturalWidth');

   $(this).height(imgHeight);
    $(this).width(imgWidth);

    $(this).mousemove(function(e) {

      var relativeX = e.clientX;
      var relativeY = e.clientY;

    console.log(relativeX+ ' ' +relativeY);
      img.css({'left': relativeX / -6 + 'px', 'top': relativeY / -1.0 + 'px'});
      });
  }, function(){

     img.css({'position': 'relative', 'top': 0,'left': 0});
     $(this).height(trueHeight);
     $(this).width(trueWidth);

  });
});
```

Пример [codepen](http://codepen.io/CoolS2/pen/OWWLJb)

Получилось не очень, все прыгает, дергается и хотелось бы знать, может есть готовые решения? Или может кто посоветует как улучшить мой "код", может кто уже делал подобное и готов поделиться! 
Спасибо!

Comment: При наведении на картинку она должна увеличиваться и при вождении по увеличинной она должна по бокам двигаться?

Comment: И у вас ничего не дёргается. Какой браузер используете?

Comment: Я просто до сих пор эксперементирую ) попробуйте сейчас, использую chrome

Comment: Покажите мне ссылку с этой функцией и я попробую её реализовать, если у вас не выйдет

Comment: Вот готовый вариант http://www.edgehunting.com/samick-sage-review/

Comment: Таа... это простецкая функция. Судя по тому, как они её реализовали

Comment: Ну, было бы здорово увидеть в ваш вариант )

Comment: Если успех написать за пол часа, то покажу, а если нет, то через 4 часа или завтра :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот я набросал такой вариант. Я любитель сложных уравнений, так что разбирайтесь и пользуйтесь :)

```js
$(function() {
  var imagebox = $('.imagebox');
  imagebox.mousemove(function(e) {
    var cursor_position = {
      x: e.clientX - $(this).offset().left + $(window).scrollLeft(), // Положение курсора слева
      y: e.clientY - $(this).offset().top + $(window).scrollTop() // Положение курсора сверху
    },
    imagebox__img = $(this).find('.imagebox__img'),
    image_position = {
      left: ((cursor_position.x / $(this).innerWidth()) * imagebox__img.width() - cursor_position.x) * -1, // Вычисляем позицию картинки слева
      top: ((cursor_position.y / $(this).innerHeight()) * imagebox__img.height() - cursor_position.y) * -1 // Вычисляем позицию картинки сверху
    }
    imagebox__img.css({
      position: 'absolute', 
      top: image_position.top, 
      left: image_position.left
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.imagebox {
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="imagebox">
  <img class="imagebox__img" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Jom-LKUuPgI/maxresdefault.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Круто, получилось как и хотел, спасибо ) http://codepen.io/CoolS2/pen/OWWLJb

Comment: @АлександрРейдзан, не за что :)